# Python: use a global list in a callback function

Tags: python

This is my callback function and I set the rcv_buffer to be global

```
def rx_callback(ok, payload):
    global n_rcvd, n_right, rcv_buffer
    n_rcvd += 1
    (pktno,) = struct.unpack('!H', payload[0:2])
    if ok:
        n_right += 1
        rcv_buffer.append((pktno, payload))
```

And in the main() I continuously check the buffer to see whether the buffer is empty:

```
   while 1:
        while len(rcv_buffer) > 0:
            (pktno, payload) = rcv_buffer.pop(0)
            print 'pktno = ', pktno, 'payload = ', payload[2:]
```

But I didn't do any synchronizations! Can I be sure that my operations on the list will not crash?Thanks!

Comment: What does your CPU utilization look like?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand you, in fact I'm just testing some codes in gnuradio and I don't know how to interact with the callback function.@keith

Comment: Well, just curious. You seem to have an infinite loop that will chew up 100% CPU most of the time.

Comment: Is that code run in a thread? Or? What's its context?

Comment: @soulseekah: I assumed there was a separate callback thread, but it would be good to have that confirmed by the OP.

Comment: Sorry now I don't know how the gnuradio work myself, but I can tell you the rx_callback is in main() and the second code block is in main(), is this enough?@soulseekah

Comment: Oh, I really don't care about that, now I just care about the safety of my code.@keith

Comment: @cloudygoose I'm confused, can you paste more code? What calls `rx_callback`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CPython, this is safe due to the interpreted nature of the execution, and due to the [Global Interpeter Lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock) (which ensures that only a single bytecode from a single thread is executing at any given time).

Other Python implementations might be quite so forgiving though...